# InApp purchase products request delegate sometimes returning products as invalid

Tags: objective-c, ios8, in-app-purchase, xcode6.1

**InApp purchase - productsRequest:didReceiveResponse: sometimes returns valid product identifiers as invalidProductIdentifiers & it works fine some times. I am using sandbox account for testing. Is it because frequent hits to the server?**